# How to change the date of the post in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the date of the post, when I publish the post.
I wrote in my plugin

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'myPlugin_published' );

function myPlugin_published()
{
    $postdate = '2010-02-23 18:57:33';/*For example*/

    $new_post = array(
       'post_date' => $postdate
    );

    wp_insert_post($new_post);
}
```

The problem is that the date is not changed.

How to change the date of the post in WordPress ?

Comment: from where date will come?

Comment: add_action( 'publish_post', 'myPlugin_published',10,1); and then `function myPlugin_published($date)`this `$date` having post date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you all for the help

```
function my_function( $post_id )
        {
            $postdate = '2010-02-23 18:57:33';

            $my_args = array(
               'ID' => $post_id,
               'post_date' => $postdate
            );

            if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){

                    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
                    remove_action('save_post', 'my_function');

                    // update the post, which calls save_post again
                    wp_update_post( $my_args );

                    // re-hook this function
                    add_action('save_post', 'my_function');
            }
        }
        add_action('save_post', 'my_function');
```

Answer (score 2):

At this time the post is already saved. Use [`wp_update_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) instead:

```
add_action( 'publish_post', 'myPlugin_published', 10, 2 );

function myPlugin_published( $ID, $post )
{
    $postdate = '2010-02-23 18:57:33';/*For example*/

    $update_post = array(
        'ID' => $ID,
        'post_date' => $postdate
    );

    wp_update_post( $update_post );
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in W:\domains\localhost\website1\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 2565

Answer (score -3):

On the post editor screen, under the Publish meta box you will see the option to publish the post immediately. Right next to it, there is an edit link. Clicking on the edit link will display the post’s time and date settings.

[image]

Using the date and time settings, you can choose any date and time in the past as well as in the future. Choosing a future date and time will allow you to schedule the post to be published on that time.
[image]

On the other hand, choosing a date and time in the past will update the date and change the post’s position in your site’s archive pages. For example if you change the month of a post from June to January, then it will appear on the January’s monthly archive page even if you just published that post. The post will also appear accordingly on the all posts list page in the admin area.

[image]

This is particularly useful when you want to publish an article, but don’t want it to appear on the front page of your site. You can just back date it to a date earlier than the last post on your site’s front-page.